# Plain text with .gif extension in Ubuntu

Tags: gif, resolution

Well here´s the thing, I am using the Terminal to do this. With a text editor such as ***nano*** I create a plain text file with the content: "GIF89a2017" and I save it as **rare.gif**

Here´s the thing, when I do ***file rare.gif*** it gives me this output: ***rare.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 12338 x 14129*** and that is indicating that it is a GIF image with a resolution of **12338 x 14129** and that's what I don't understand. Where´s that resolution coming from?

Another thing is, I thought extension didn't really decide what type of file it is, for example when I take a **.gif** and convert it into and **.exe** it still recognises it as a GIF image with the ***file*** command. I'm gonna guess that in the problem that I have it is recognised as a GIF image because it was created with the GIF extension but I'd like to know why.

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where´s that resolution coming from?

It's coming from the (bogus) GIF89 header you put in the file. The four bytes following "GIF89a" define the width and height. Each one is stored as a 16-bit unsigned integer. The characters you put there -- `2017` -- are interpreted as:

```
32 30 ("20") -- 0x3032 = 12338
31 37 ("17") -- 0x3731 = 14129
```

> I'm gonna guess that in the problem that I have it is recognised as a GIF image because it was created with the GIF extension but I'd like to know why.

No, `file` doesn't look at extensions. It's because the file had a semi-valid GIF header. If you changed the header to something that didn't start with "GIF89a", it will no longer be recognized as a GIF.

Comment: Okay that sounds good, but sorry I'm just starting and I didn't really understand how you made that conversion from 20 to 32 30 and from 17 to 31 37. To me it just seems like adding a 3 in front but I'm sure that is not how it's done. I'm not gonna ask you to explain everything to me if you don't want to, but maybe you could redirect me to somewhere I can learn it from. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The numbers are represented by the hex values of their ASCII code, e.g., "2" has an ASCII code of 42 and the hex of 42 is 32. The resolution is the decimal value of the concatenated hex values so "20" becomes 3230 or in hex representation 0x3230 which has a decimal value of 12338.